# My processor speed drops to 800 Mhz when my Lenovo Thinkpad W541 is plugged into the OEM cable

Tags: cpu, performance, thinkpad, throttling, cpu-z

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad W541 (Windows 10). The processor is i7 4810MQ. My power settings are "high performance", with max processor speed at 100%.

Always worked well in the past 4 years. Now, I noticed my laptop getting super slow. I did some checking with a numerical simulation running in the background that usually sends me the CPU to 100%. I checked with CPU-Z, and all cores are at 800 MHZ (multiplier=8)  when the laptop is plugged into the OEM cable, which charges fine.

Whenever I disconnect the cable, the CPU speed jumps to 3600 MHZ (multiplier=36) and Laptop is again super fast. How can I fix this?

[Some Superuser fellows suggest](https://superuser.com/questions/985119/intel-cpu-using-low-clock-for-no-reason) to remove the Intel(R) Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework DLL here c:\Windows\System32\Intel\DPTF\DptfPolicyConfigTdp.dll but I did a search in my drives and I have nothing named DPTF.

I tried [the suggestion on this post for a Dell laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/1160735/stop-dell-from-throttling-cpu-with-power-adapter), I installed ThrottleStop, and unticked "BD PROCHOT" and clicked "save". Nothing changed.

I tried even to force the multiplier to 36 within ThrottleStop, but nothing. Any suggestion? See also the high-performance settings below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with the W541 more than a year ago, and it came down to the machine perceiving that it was getting insufficient power, and throttling down the CPU as a result.   In my case, when the OEM adapter was plugged in, the power-settings switched to "Airplane" mode, which is a severely reduced power plan.  Check what power plan you're running under when you're in this 800Mhz reduced performance state.  While the subject line is a different issue, [this thread fundamentally describes the problem and the solution](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-P-and-W-Series-Mobile/Lenovo-Think-Pad-W541-does-not-charge-recognise-AC-adapter/td-p/4302231).

(If you check "Control Panel -> All -> Power Options -> Airplane -> Change plan settings -> Change advanced power settings -> Processor power management - Minimum processor state", you'll see that for Minimum processor state, both "on battery" and "plugged in" are set to 5%, which was the source of my problem.)

If that doesn't resolve the issue, others have found the following to resolve the throttled-CPU issue:

1. Shutdown windows
2. Disconnect Power plug.
3. Take out battery
4. Press Power button couple of times (laptop wont start as no battery or power but this would drain any remain charge inside mobo)
5. Put battery back in and plug back power (Issue should be solved Now)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue - when I plugged in suddenly cpu speed dropped from various around 2.6 GHz to fixed 0.78 constant. This is Lenovo P53.

What helped in my case was to STOP "Lenovo Intelligent Thermal Solution Service" in Services App. I disabled the service so it wont come back after the restart.

Looks like it is not that intelligent after all...

Answer (score 0):

The AC adapter's connector maybe damaged. It has a central pin that is used to inform the PM software about its wattage. When a lower wattage AC adapter is connected, the laptop slows down to not overrun the power supply while charging. When AC adapter is removed all is back to normal on battery power.

First thing to do is to test with another similar AC adapter.