# Notebook with 2.7GHz i7 processor is stuck at a clock speed of 0.8GHz

Tags: windows, ubuntu, laptop, cpu, performance

I have a Dell Latitude 5411 Notebook. It has a Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10850H CPU @ 2.70GHz processor, 32GB DDR4 memory and a GeForce MX250 GPU.

Despite this quite powerful processor the performance of this laptop is extremely poor. I have a dual boot system with windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. On Windows the performance is so poor, that the computer is almost unusable. Even the most simple things like opening a text based website can be very slow. On Ubuntu doing the normal things like opening websites and browsing files or launching simple applications works fine. However, when I run a slightly more ressource hungry process like a simulation tool or Inkskape or whatever I can also see that the performance is definitely not what it should be.

When I run the Task manager on windows or `lscpu` on Ubuntu, I can see, that the processor is constantly running on 0.8GHz, no matter what I am doing.

To solve this problem I tried a lot of things (on Windows at least). I Installed a couple of Dell tools like the `Dell Power Manager` and `Dell Command Update` and ran them. Sometimes when I switch the power mode in Dell Power Manager from quiet to something else I get a short time with normal processor clock speeds between 1.5Ghz and 3.0Ghz. But it randomly switches back to 800MHz and doesn't go back up anymore. Even when the power setting is on "Ultra Performance", it doesn't change anything. I also updated my BIOS to the newest version which also didn't help.

When I went to the BIOS setting and switched off "Intel Speed Step", I got an extremely high clock speed of around 4.5GHz. But as I read that this is an easy way to kill your CPU, I went back turned Intel Speed Step back on.

Does anyone have a suggestion how I can fix the issue? I'd prefer a solution that works for both OS, but just one of them would be fine, too.

Comment: try check this question https://superuser.com/questions/985119/intel-cpu-using-low-clock-for-no-reason.

Comment: @DarkBeccio Thanks for the hint, unfortunately none of those answers solved my problem